# show image when person detected

Tags: python, opencv

I have a real-time facial recognition program that can identify the faces of people known to me
And then write the person's name on it.
Now, when someone such as 'Alex' is detected, then I'll show the image I've seen for this person and close it after a few seconds, and again new people
This is a piece of my code:

```
for face_encoding in face_encodings:
           # match = face_recognition.compare_faces(known_face_encoding, face_encoding)
           # Matches=np.where(match)[0] #Checking which image is matched
            face_distances=face_recognition.face_distance(face_encodings, face_encoding)
            Matches =list(face_distances<= 0.4)
            name="Unknown"

            if True in Matches:
               match_index = np.argmin(face_distances)
               name = known_person[match_index]
            face_names.append(name)
```

As you can see, the name represents the people's name
how i do it??please help me
thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

Your question is unclear, but anyway, once you have correctly identified the name of the person and you want to display his/her image to screen, just use the imshow function from the OpenCV library.

Here a code snippet that might help you get there:

```
import cv2  

#YOUR CODE LOGIC ... --> you get the name of the person that has been detected

if (name == "Alex"):
    picture = cv2.imread("Alex.jpg")
    cv2.imshow(name, picture)
    cv2.waitKey()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: thank you,but i mean is for example I have 10 names and 10 images for each name, and I want them to be 5 seconds on the screen whenever they detect them, and then the image is closed, and again, if someone else is seen, it's the same way.

Comment: @rkoofoo you mean 5 seconds for each of the 10 images per name?

Comment: yes ,its exactly ,What I have to do is to use Dictionaries in Python,but i havent't any idea

Comment: Yes, I will definitely do this with great thanks,i have a problem,when i detect.i just a problem when I detect more than one person, I'm likely to encounter an error when two people are in front of the camera.